# Distributing work in scala

Tags: scala

Below is a script to distribute jobs amongst workers while trying to maintain an even distribution of work and considering that not every worker can do every task.  The solution I used is to find every possible legal combination of work distributions and pick the distribution with the least variance in workload between workers.

I'm looking for optimizations of the algorithm and designs to make the solution more extensible.  I've already tried using `ParSeq` instead of `Stream` in `solutionsFrom` but I didn't see any noticable improvement, but maybe that was because of the small sample size.

First we have Tasks which have an ID for reference, a weight which can indicate any metric of workload (say minutes to complete), and a description of the task.

```
case class Task(id: Int, weight: Int, job: String)
```

Workers have an ID for reference, a list of tasks to accomplish and a predicate that checks if the worker can do the task.  The class is immutable so assigning a task creates a new worker object.

```
case class Worker(id: Int, tasks: List[Task], canDo: Task => Boolean) {
  require(tasks.forall(canDo))

  lazy val weight: Int = {
    tasks.toStream.map(_.weight).sum // toStream to convert from Set
  }

  def assigned(task: Task): Option[Worker] = {
    if (canDo(task)) Some(Worker(id, task :: tasks, canDo))
    else None
  }

}
```

The state is the current distribution of workloads on the workers and the remaining tasks.  As we move from a state, we take a task from the remaining and add it to a worker.  I originally had just `task <- remaining` but that resulted in duplicate distributions that were just distributed in a different orders which I don't think matters.

```
case class State(workers: Set[Worker], remaining: Set[Task]) {

  lazy val moves: Stream[State] = {
    for {
      task      <- remaining.headOption.toStream
      oldWorker <- workers
      newWorker <- oldWorker.assigned(task)
    } yield State(workers - oldWorker + newWorker, remaining - task)
  }
}
```

This is the *solver* object.  It generates a stream of all possible solutions, cases were there are no more valid moves then picks the solution with the minimum variance in workloads.

```
object Distributer {

  def solutionsFrom(state: State): Stream[State] = {
    if (state.moves.isEmpty) Stream(state)
    else state.moves.flatMap(solutionsFrom(_))
  }

  def optimumSolutionFrom(state: State): State = {
    solutionsFrom(state).minBy(varianceOfState(_))
  }

  private def mean(xs: Seq[Int]): Double = {
    if (xs.size == 0) 0
    else xs.sum / xs.size.toDouble
  }

  private def variance(xs: Seq[Int]): Double = {
     val avg = mean(xs)
     val squares = xs.map(x => x * x)
     mean(squares) - (avg * avg)
  }

  def varianceOfState(state: State): Double = {
    val weights = state.workers.toStream.map(_.weight) // toStream to convert from Set
    variance(weights)
  }

}
```

Here is some code for demonstration.  You should be able to just concatenate my code blocks and run this all as one script.

```
val startingworkers = Set(
  Worker(0, Nil, (t: Task) => t.job == "Sweep"),
  Worker(1, Nil, (t: Task) => t.job == "Cook"),
  Worker(2, Nil, (t: Task) => true),
  Worker(3, Nil, (t: Task) => t.job == "Wipe" || t.job == "Sweep")
)

val startingTasks = Set(
  Task(0, 12,  "Sweep"),
  Task(1, 5,   "Cook"),
  Task(2, 101, "Sweep"),
  Task(3, 23,  "Sweep"),
  Task(4, 11,  "Cook"),
  Task(5, 122, "Cook"),
  Task(6, 99,  "Sweep"),
  Task(7, 65,  "Wipe"),
  Task(8, 58,  "Wipe"),
  Task(9, 222, "Laundry")
)

val start     = State(startingworkers, startingTasks)
val solutions = Distributer.solutionsFrom(start).toList
val variances = solutions.groupBy(Distributer.varianceOfState(_))
val optimum   = variances.keySet.min
val solution  = variances(optimum).head
println(s"#solutions:      ${solutions.size}")
println(s"max varaince:    ${variances.keySet.max}")
println(s"optimum variance $optimum")
solution.workers foreach { Worker: Worker =>
  println(s"Worker #${Worker.id}")
  Worker.tasks foreach { task: Task =>
    println(s"  Task ID: ${task.id}, Job: ${task.job}, Minutes to complete: ${task.weight}")
  }
}
```